# System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I have to create a new object and copy all the fields form the old one to a new one and it is a child to opportunity.

The copyfields is a method that copies the fields from one object to another and the function call line in the cloning method is the line where I am getting the  exception.

```
public LQAgreementCloneCtrl(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    lqa = [Select off1stdate__c, hosp1stdate__c, Zip_Code_New__c, X66_Contract__c,WAWF__c,,AccountRevenue__c 
         From LQ_Agreement__c Where id=:ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];
    o = [Select of_Hospitals__c, X8_Gal__c, X4_Gal__c, X3mo_Avg_LBS_stop__c, X3_Gal__c,   
            X2_Gal__c, X1st_Pick_Up_Date__c, X17_Gal__c, X12_month_Actual_Stops__c,
            X12_mo_Avg_Rev__c,   Waste_Destruction_Date__c,   WS_Other__c,   Vision_Match__c, 
            Value_analysis_committee__c, AR_FuelFee__c,   AR_FixerFee__c,   AR_EnergyFee__c,   APPROVALS__c,RecordType.Name   
         From Opportunity WHERE Id=:lqa.Opportunity__c];
}

public PageReference cloning(){
    if(lqa.Status__c=='Deal Approved'){
        //oclone=o;
        //oclone.id=null;
        oclone=o.clone();
        insert oclone;
        System.debug('Oclone>>>>>>>'+oclone);       
        LQ_Agreement__c lqaclone=new LQ_agreement__c(); 
        //lqaclone=new LQ_Agreement__c();
        lqaclone.Opportunity__c=oclone.Id;
        System.debug('LQAClone>>>>>'+lqaclone);
        lqaclone=copyfields(lqaclone,lqa);
        oclone.Name=o.Name+'-Amended';
        //Checking the Record type of the original Opportunity to create the new cloned Opp with RecordType of same waste stream + amendment added
        if(o.RecordType.Name=='LQ Bio/SMS Renewal'|| o.RecordType.Name=='LQ Bio/SMS New Business' )
            oclone.RecordType.Name='LQ BIO/SMS Amendment';
        if(o.RecordType.Name=='LQ Haz Waste New Business'|| o.RecordType.Name=='LQ Haz Waste Renewal' )
            oclone.RecordType.Name='LQ Haz Waste Amendment';
        if(o.RecordType.Name=='LQ RMW New Business'|| o.RecordType.Name=='LQ RMW Renewal' )
            oclone.RecordType.Name='LQ RMW Amendment';
        if(o.RecordType.Name=='LQ Rx/Pharma New Business'|| o.RecordType.Name=='LQ Rx/Pharma Renewal' )
            oclone.RecordType.Name='LQ Rx/Pharma Amendment';


        //Checking the Record type of the original LQ Agreement to create the new cloned LQA with RecordType + amendment added          
        if(lqa.RecordType.Name=='LQ Existing Agreement' || lqa.RecordType.Name=='LQ New Agreement' )
            lqaclone.RecordType.Name='LQ New Agreement – Amendment';
        if(lqa.RecordType.Name=='LQ Existing Agreement GPO' || lqa.RecordType.Name=='LQ New Agreement GPO' )
            lqaclone.RecordType.Name='LQ New Agreement GPO – Amendment';

        insert lqaclone;
        update oclone;
        p=new ApexPages.StandardController(lqaclone).view();    
    }
    else{
        System.debug('Inside Else statement');
        p=new ApexPages.StandardController(lqa).view(); 
    }
    return p;           
}



 public LQ_Agreement__c copyfields(LQ_Agreement__c lqaclone1,LQ_Agreement__c lqa1){
        lqaclone1.Approved_By_RSD__c=lqa1.Approved_By_RSD__c;
        lqaclone1.ApprovedByBrent__c=lqa1.ApprovedByBrent__c;
        lqaclone1.ApprovedByJIM__c=lqa1.ApprovedByJIM__c;
        lqaclone1.ApprovedByVP__c=lqa1.ApprovedByVP__c;
}
```

**I am getting the exception at the function call to copyfields. The exception I get is Attempt to de-reference null object. Copy fields is a big function. I just gave a few lines**

Comment: are you sure thats exactly here the error is occurring? there is no dereferencing at that line. What does the debug output say?

Comment: 10:40:56.146 (1146991000)|METHOD_ENTRY|[130]|01pV00000004cUM|LQAgreementCloneCtrl.copyfields(LQ_Agreement__c, LQ_Agreement__c)
10:40:56.149 (1149726000)|METHOD_EXIT|[130]|01pV00000004cUM|LQAgreementCloneCtrl.copyfields(LQ_Agreement__c, LQ_Agreement__c)
10:40:56.150 (1150241000)|FATAL_ERROR|System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Answer (score 3):

Error is after copyfield, my guess is that your `oclone.recordType` sub-object is not defined, `clone` on its own does not replicate it, it can only come from SOQL result. Also you cannot assign oclone.recordType.name, to assign record type to clone you must assign proper RecordType Id to `oclone.RecordTypeId` field.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why just using the standard SObject.clone(false, true) method wouldn't suffice (false - don't preserve the Id and true - make a true copy, not just a reference). A list of SObjects can similarly be truly cloned with List.deepClone(false) instead of crafting your own clone/copy logic.

In general I'd consider cleaning up your logic so that you can *see* the flow of your code more clearly, especially in terms of what state and values your variables should have. For example from your code:

```
LQ_Agreement__c lqaclone=new LQ_agreement__c();
//lqaclone=new LQ_Agreement__c();
lqaclone.Opportunity__c=oclone.Id;
System.debug('LQAClone>>>>>'+lqaclone);
lqaclone=copyfields(lqaclone,lqa);
```

It seems the following was intended, assuming copyfields returned a *new* SObject:

```
LQ_Agreement__c lqaclone = copyfields(lqaclone, lqa);
lqaclone.Opportunity__c = oclone.Id;
```

But again, the following seems correct to me:

```
LQ_Agreement__c lqaclone = lqa.clone(false, true);
```

unless I'm missing some other reason that you preferred to roll your own clone.